# Hide a parent block (display:none) if child element content text

Tags: javascript, css, angular, css-selectors

[image]i need to hide a block of `<button>` element in context menu (display:none) if child of `<button>` have text `<span trans"">Remove</span>`.

```
<div id="cdk-overlay-0" class="cdk-overlay-pane context-menu-overlay" style="pointer-events: auto; position: static;">
    <drive-context-menu class="context-menu">
        <context-actions-container>
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <button class="context-menu-item ng-star-inserted">
                <mat-icon class="mat-icon notranslate mat-icon-no-color" role="img" aria-hidden="true">

                    <span trans="">Preview</span>
            </button>
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <button class="context-menu-item ng-star-inserted">
                <span trans="">Aggiungi al mio drive privato</span>
            </button>
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            [..........]
        </context-actions-container>
    </drive-context-menu>
</div>
```

I try next example of css and all of this rules hide all of menus item (button) but i wont hide a single  if have text specific.

```
div[id^="cdk-overlay-"] .context-menu context-actions-container button {
    display: none;
}

button.context-menu-item.ng-star-inserted  {
    display: none;
}
.context-menu { 
      display: none;
}

.context-menu-item .ng-star-inserted {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: please try to be more specific.
and share what you have tried.

Comment: This is not possible with CSS alone -> [Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text)

Comment: I need to hide a button if inside the block button i have span with specific content in block.

Answer (score 2):

you can `display none` using jQuery please try below code to display none button if span have "Remove"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.context-menu span').each(function () {      
      if($(this).html()==='Remove'){
        $(this).parents('button').css("display","none");
      }
    });   
  })
</script>
```

For above code you need reference jQuery in your webpage (if you have already jquery then no need to reference)
Hope this work :)

Comment: I try this script (reference jQuery is on page) but not working!

Comment: I update the first message with screenshot of code of page and element...

Answer (score 1):

One approach to achieve this effect is to:

- add the declaration: `.remove {display: none;}` to the stylesheet
- search for the right sort of button using javascript
- add the class `.remove` to every button which matches all the conditions

**Working Example:**

```js
const contextMenuButtons = [... document.getElementsByClassName('context-menu-item')];

for (contextMenuButton of contextMenuButtons) {

  if (contextMenuButton.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].textContent === 'Remove') {

    contextMenuButton.classList.add('remove');
  }
}
```

```css
.remove {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="context-menu-item ng-star-inserted">
  <span trans="">Aggiungi al mio drive privato</span>
</button>

<button class="context-menu-item ng-star-inserted">
  <span trans="">Remove</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for message..i try this script but not working to span or button !

Comment: I update first message in this topic to clarify the problem...

Comment: When you run the code snippet above, you will see that `<button class="context-menu-item ng-star-inserted"><span trans="">Remove</span></button>` has the style `display: none` applied to it.

Comment: i know, but in website not working. Script is correctly loaded in page, but dont add class .remove to nothing ..

Comment: I found the problem...your code not working because the element <button> is an element that is added dynamically in javascript..after the script is loaded... Do you know jQuery code to apply dinamically this action? thanks

Comment: You need to contain the code in a function and then invoke the function at the right time.